# mingw-make install with admin privileges

Tags: mingw, mingw32

I am pretty certain this question has been answered somewhere because it seems pretty basic but I can't find anything.

I am trying to build the Qjson lib. For that I am following the build orders of http://qjson.sourceforge.net/build/

I had an error when doing the "**mingw32-make install**"

```
CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:51 (file):
  file cannot create directory: C:/Program Files (x86)/qjson/lib/cmake/qjson.
  Maybe need administrative privileges.
```

And if I create the file myself, I then have an other error later:

```
CMake Error at cmake_install.cmake:51 (file):
  file INSTALL cannot copy file
```

So I guess it is still an admin privileges.

**How can I do the "mingw-make install" with admin privileges?**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You may try to install it elsewhere by using the option `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/path/to/custom/dir` as you type `cmake`

Comment: Yep you are right, that was plan B solution :), I guess that will do !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as suggested by francis, let's go for plan B solution: **change directory of installation** where mingw does not need admin privileges. This will be on my second disk D: for me.

I don't know if my manip is the best one, but I still write it down here in case of it can help:

As everything was already compiled, so I kept that, I simply modified the *CMakeCache.txt* file. What I changed:

```
//Directory where to install QJSONConfig.cmake
CMAKECONFIG_INSTALL_DIR:PATH=D:/Qjson

[...other stuff unchanged...]

//Install path prefix, prepended onto install directories.
CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=D:/Qjson

[...other stuff unchanged...]

//The directory the headers are installed in
INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR:PATH=D:/Qjson/include

//Directory where lib will install
LIB_INSTALL_DIR:STRING=D:/Qjson/lib
```

and then again in the console:

```
mingw32-make install
```

That successfully created bin, include, and lib folders.

Thanks.

Comment: Yep, waiting to be allowed to.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way how to do that namely by starting your command prompt (or PowerShell) as administrator. This automatically adjusts the writing and reading access of your `mingw32-make.exe` (or the 64bit equivalent). A collegue of mine just pointed that out (since I haven't used Windows in like 2 1/2 - 3 years :D) and it worked. I just finished building VTK 7.0 on Windows 10 and did `mingw32-make.exe install` inside the `build` folder of VTK's folder structure (it's based on `cmake`) and it worked. Installation destination in my case was `C:\VTK`.